# Detecting device JS and toggle class

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I want to detect a device width and height (responsive layout), so if return is true I want to toggle class "mobile" but I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

```
$(function detectmob() {
    if(window.innerWidth <= 720 && window.innerHeight <= 1280) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (return=true) {
        $(document).getElementByClass("box").addClass ('mobile');
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for any of this; you should use media queries in your CSS file instead. Here's the code you're looking to implement: https://pastebin.com/bkYXEjPb

Comment: Thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning true, you could just add the class there

Answer (score 0):

`return` will exit out of the function from when it is encountered. You are looking for a variable isolated to `detectmob` based on which a class can be added.

```
function detectmob() {
  var isMobile = false;

  if (window.innerWidth <= 720 && window.innerHeight <= 1280) {
    isMobile = true;
  }

  if (isMobile) {
    $(document).getElementByClass("box").addClass('mobile');
  }
}
```

But if you still want to check based on the return value then the logic has to be extracted out into a function which can have a return value.

```
function detectmob() {
  var isMob = isMobile();

  if (isMob) {
    $(document).getElementByClass("box").addClass('mobile');
  }
}

function isMobile() {
  return window.innerWidth <= 720 && window.innerHeight <= 1280;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use user agent instead of screen size otherwise mobile with a huge resolution will be detected as PC (eg Pixel 2 XL have 1440 x 2880 screen). Also user may resize browser window on PC to 700x1000 and your code will detect it as mobile.

Comment: Here is small js library based on user agent detection https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile